# Cancel form submission when entries are invalid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am working on a form with multiple fields and of course, a submit button.
How do I cancel the form submission if some fields are empty?
I tried putting a validation of javascript, `input type="submit" onclick="check()"` on the submit button.

But what I actually want is that, the page won't load so that, all other information in the text fields won't go away.
Like, what if the form has 100 fields and the user forgot to input one field and click the submit, it will show him an error message and all other fields will be cleared so he has to type it again.
I'm trying to prevent that.

I have multiple options to create this effect but I am currently trying to find a way on doing this.
Any other ways would be appreciated (like disabling the button when all mandatory fields are not filled, then enabling it at when everything is complete)

Comment: Remember that any Javascript check is not enough. You will ALWAYS have to check entries sever sides PHP to be sure of inputs.

Answer (score 2):

if the condition will be false click(event) returns false and nothing will happend

```
function check(){

    if(validate === false)
       return false;

}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: OH, thanks! I actually bumped into this answer before I asked. But it didn't work for me, only to find out that the return false was inside my php tags. I reread your answer and realized it myself. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `return false` from inside your `check` function to prevent the form from submitting.